# Java - Recursive Permutation?

Tags: java, permutation

Hy Guys,
I have something like this:

```
  String keyBase = "keyA";
  String[] valueBase = {"a1","a2","a3"};

  String keyLevel1 = "keyB";
  String[] valueLevel1 = {"b1","b2","b3"};

  String keyLevel2 = "keyC";
  String[] valueLevel2 = {"c1","c2","c3"};
```

And need something like this:

```
String[][] f1 = {{"keyA","a1"},{"keyB","b1"}{"keyC","c1"}}
String[][] f2 = {{"keyA","a1"},{"keyB","b1"}{"keyC","c2"}}
String[][] f2 = {{"keyA","a1"},{"keyB","b1"}{"keyC","c3"}}

String[][] f5 = {{"keyA","a1"},{"keyB","b2"}{"keyC","c1"}}
String[][] f6 = {{"keyA","a1"},{"keyB","b2"}{"keyC","c2"}}
...
```

What's a simple but good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a set cross-product, not a permutation. what have you tried??

Comment: I would start with the Guava method Collections2.permutations

Comment: ...and for the cartesian product part there is also a Guava method: Sets.cartesianProduct

Comment: Using `String[][] f1` to `f6` or further is only possible to hardcode this. Or do you want a `String[][][]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about recursive permutation. 
I just tried based on your output.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <3 ; i++) {
   for(int j = 0 ; j <3 ; j++) {
      for(int k = 0 ; k <3 ; k++) {
         system.out.println(keyBase +","+ valueBase[i] +","+
                            keyLevel1  +","+ valueLevel1[j]  +","+
                            keyLevel2  +","+ valueLevel2[k] )
      }
   }
 }
```